# How can I split a template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an HTML document:

```
<body>
    {{> today_list}}    
</body>
```

And template:

```
<template name="today_list">
   {{#if action_log_mode}}
   ...
   {{/if}}


   {{#if action_list_mode}}
   ...
   {{/if}}
</template>
```

Is it possible to split this template to two others.  Something like this:

```
<body>
  {{#if action_log_mode}}
    {{> one}}
  {{/if}}   
  {{#if action_list_mode}}
    {{> two}}
  {{/if}}   
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have any number of templates, and they may be nested. They may be in the same, or different .html files.

I don't know without testing whether or not you can scope a template helper in body (outside a template). Template helpers are scoped to a specific template. 'one', for example, `Template.one.listItem = function () { ...` will not be accessible in template 'two'. However, you can add a global helper (which might work in `<body>`), like so (taken from the [Meteor wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars)):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("foo", function() {
  return "blah"; // (calculate value here)
});
```

What absolutely would work is:

In app.html

```
<body>
  {{ > page }}
</body>

<template name="page">
   {{#if isLogMode}}
     {{ > one }}
   {{else}}
     {{ > two }}
   {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="one">
  ...
</template>

<template name="two">
  ...
</template>
```

In app.js

```
Template.page.isLogMode = function () {
  // (something like)
  return Session.get('logMode') === "log";
};
```